# Binary function - integrated over one variable - still continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Consider a binary uniform continuous function $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \mapsto [0,1]$.
Let $g(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)dy$.

Is $g(x)$ still a continuous function? If not, what constraints we can add to make $g(x)$ continuous?

What I have tried: Given that $f(x,y)$ is uniform continuous, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta$, s.t. $|f(x,y)-f(x+\delta,y)|\leq \epsilon$ (for all $y$). Therefore, $|g(x)-g(x+\delta)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x,y)-f(x+\delta,y)| dy \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \epsilon dy$. However, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \epsilon dy$ is not a convergent integral and I am stuck.

Comment: $g(x)$ may not exist with just uniform continuity of $f$.

Comment: In my case, $f(x,y)$ is a joint probability density function, so one can assume $g(x)$ indeed exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is false, even if the $y$-integral exists and is finite. Consider $F(y) = \frac1{1+y^2}$ which is a map $\mathbb R\to [0,1]$ with integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(y) dy = \frac\pi2 .$$ We can rescale by setting
$$ G(t,y) =F(ty)t$$
Observe that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(t,y) dy = \frac{\pi}2$ for all $t\neq 0$. We can therefore put
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x\le 0\\ G(x,y) & 0\le x \le 1\\ G(1,y) & x\ge 1 \end{cases}$$
Which is uniformly continuous and takes values in $[0,1]$. Then we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) dy= \begin{cases} 0 & x\le 0\\ \pi/2 & x> 0 \end{cases} $$
which is not continuous.

If you want a positive result, you can try to satisfy the assumptions of [Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). The above example has "mass escaping to infinity", which DCT does not allow.

(edit) I just saw in the comments that OP's $f$ is also a probability distribution, a small modification shows that this doesn't help either. We can normalise $F$ so that $F$ has integral 1, put the same definition of $G$, and then have
$ f(x,y) = G(\max(0,-x(x-1)),y)$. Now $\int f dxdy = 1$ and $\int f(x,y) dy$ is 1 iff $0<x<1$ and 0 otherwise.